# Deserializing a customly formatted string

Tags: java, parsing, abstract-factory

The component receives a `serialized message` as a string and a `serialized schema` as a string. The `message` contains key-value pairs or just the values. The `schema` describes how to turn that `message` into a Java object. Firstly, we parse the `schema` into a Java object (schema format is known in advance). There is an `enum` with possible `data providers`, which imply the `message` format (it can be XML, JSON, or something custom). So, the `schema` contains this `enum` value as well as some additional information (like the keys if the `message` only has the values, so we can later map already known key names to values and we don't need to send the keys every time over the wire).

Now, that's how it works:

```
// Get the schema serialization format.
String schemaFormat = "XML";

// Get the schema.
Serialized schemaSerialized = new Serialized(
        "<DataProvider format=\"FIXED_LENGTH_STRING\">\n" +
        "    <variable name=\"agentId\" len=\"5\"/>\n" +
        "    <variable name=\"callsPerDay\" len=\"3\"/>\n" +
        "</DataProvider>");

// Parse the schema.
Schema schemaAbstract = Deserializer.deserializeSchema(
        schemaSerialized,
        FormatSchema.valueOf(schemaFormat));

// Downcast the schema to its real type.
XMLSchema schema = (XMLSchema) schemaAbstract;

// Get the data from the wire.         metric1 | metric2
Serialized msgSerialized = new Serialized("12230015");

// Deserialize the data.
Message msg = Deserializer.deserializeMessage(msgSerialized, schema);

// Serialize the message into JSON
String msgJson= msg.toJSONString();
```

**Result**:
   msgJson is now: {"Metrics":{"agentId":"12230","callsPerDay":"15"}}

Now, I'll explain the classes briefly (too much code to fit here):

`class` **Serialized**: Has a `String` private field, sets in the constructor, there is a getter.

`interface` **Deserialized** `extends` **Serializable**: just an empty interface. **Should I implement Serializable?** I don't really know much about it, just seems appropriate.

`interface` **Schema** `extends` **Deserialized**: represents an abstract Java Object for any kind of `schema`. Has a getter for **FormatMessage** `enum` value.

`interface` **Message** `extends` **Deserialized**: represents an abstract Java Object for any kind of `message`. Has a **toJSONString()** method.

`interface` **Parser**: empty. Because for a message I need 2 parameters, for schema one.

`interface` **ParserMessage** `extends` **Parser**: has a method `Message parse(Serialized, Schema)`

`interface` **ParserSchema** `extends` **Parser**: has a method `Schema parse(Serialized)`

`interface` **Format**: empty

`enum` **FormatMessage** `implements` **Format**

`enum` **FormatSchema** `implements` **Format**

For each **FormatMessage** value, there is a concrete class for **Message** and **ParserMessage**. For each **FormatSchema** value, there is a concrete class for **Schema** and **ParserSchema**. Obviously, **ParserSchema** returns its corresponding **Schema** and the same with messages.

Now, the main part:

`class` **Deserializer**: has 2 methods: `deserializeMessage` and `deserializeSchema`. For both he accepts a **Format** (for message in a form of schema). Inside those two methods this class uses a `Strategy pattern` by calling methods named `setParserMessage` and `setParserSchema`. Inside those methods, there is a call to a **ParserFactory** which holds all the concrete **Parser** static instances and gives away references to them by `switch-casing` by the given **Format** on the appropriate `enum`.

The problem is that I'm afraid that the **Deserializer** class abstracts everything too much that I have to cast a lot, even the caller has to cast a little. My team accepted this design, but I just want to make sure :)

**UPD**: The code for `Deserializer` and the `ParserFactory` as requested.

```
/**
 * Used to deserialize schemas and the corresponding to them messages.
 * Abstracts all the Parser implementations and uses the Strategy design pattern to switch between them based on the Format using the ParserFactory.
 */
public class Deserializer {

    private static ParserMessage parserMessage;
    private static ParserSchema  parserSchema;

    private Deserializer() {} // Imitating a static class

    /**
     * Deserializes a schema into the concrete Schema object.
     * The returned object can be later used to deserialize the actual messages sent by the corresponding provider.
     *
     * @param schema       a serialized schema
     * @param schemaFormat the serialization type of the schema
     * @return this schema as a Java object
     */
    public static Schema deserializeSchema(Serialized schema,
                                           FormatSchema schemaFormat
                                          ) {

        setParserSchema(schemaFormat); // Strategy pattern
        return parserSchema.parse(schema);
    }

    /**
     * Deserializes a message into the concrete Message object.
     *
     * @param msg    a serialized message
     * @param schema the schema as a Java object
     * @return this message as a Java object
     */
    public static Message deserializeMessage(Serialized msg,
                                             Schema schema
                                            ) {

        setParserMessage(schema.getFormatMessage()); // Strategy pattern
        return parserMessage.parse(msg, schema);
    }

    private static void setParserMessage(FormatMessage msgFormat) { // Strategy pattern

        parserMessage = ParserFactory.getParserMessage(msgFormat); // Factory pattern
    }

    private static void setParserSchema(FormatSchema configFileFormat) { // Strategy pattern

        parserSchema = ParserFactory.getParserSchema(configFileFormat); // Factory pattern
    }
}

/**
 * Abstracts all the Parser implementations using the Factory design pattern.
 * Defines a Factory that gives away the reference at the Parser implementation instance based on the given Format implementation instance (which is an enum option value).
 * <p>
 * The factory contains a lazy-initialized static instance of each currently available Parser implementation.
 */
public class ParserFactory {

    private static final XMLSchemaParser                  XML_SCHEMA_PARSER                  = new XMLSchemaParser();
    private static final FIXED_LENGTH_STRINGMessageParser FIXED_LENGTH_STRING_MESSAGE_PARSER = new FIXED_LENGTH_STRINGMessageParser();

    private ParserFactory() {} // imitating a static class

    /**
     * Returns the ParserMessage instance for parsing messages of specific FormatMessage.
     *
     * @param msgFormat the format of the acquired Serialized message
     * @return a reference at the corresponding static ParserMessage instance. Null if not found
     * @see FormatMessage All message formats
     */
    public static ParserMessage getParserMessage(FormatMessage msgFormat) {

        switch (msgFormat) {
            case FIXED_LENGTH_STRING:
                return getFixedLengthStringMessageParserInstance();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the ParserSchema instance for parsing schemas of specific FormatSchema.
     *
     * @param schemaFormat format of the Serialized schema
     * @return reference at the corresponding static ParserSchema instance. Null if not found
     * @see FormatSchema All schema formats
     */
    public static ParserSchema getParserSchema(FormatSchema schemaFormat) {

        switch (schemaFormat) {
            case XML:
                return getXmlSchemaParser();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private static XMLSchemaParser getXmlSchemaParser() {
        return XML_SCHEMA_PARSER;
    }

    private static FixedLengthStringMessageParser getFixedLengthStringMessageParserInstance() {
        return FIXED_LENGTH_STRING_MESSAGE_PARSER;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I'll try to review that which you have provided. Since you didn't post all the relevant code, I might have misunderstood some of your descriptions, so I'll base my review on how I understood them.

First, I suggest you get rid of the class `Serialized`. The way you describe it, `Serialized` only seems to be a wrapper class for a `String`, without any functionality. I really don't see a point in that. You might as well use a `String` itself whenever you deal with a serialized representation of something.

Then, about your empty interfaces. I don't really see why the interface `Deserialized` would be useful. As far as I could figure out your description, there is no case where a method parameter can be both a `Message` or a `Schema`, and `Deserialized` doesn't declare any methods itself, so it is completely dispensable. The same applies to `Parser` and `Format`. If the `ParserMessage` and `ParserSchema` don't even share a single method, then what's the use of them having a common superinterface?

Next, I'm not sure if I understand the purpose of the interfaces `Schema` and `Message`. They both return a `FormatSchema` and `FormatMessage`, respectively. But if I understand the design of your program correctly, then a message is deserialized using a schema, and a schema is deserialized using a schema format. So why does `Schema` have a getter for a `FormatSchema`? I thought a `FormatSchema` describes how a schema is (de-)serialized, which means that a `FormatSchema` is not a property of a `Schema`, so there is no place for a `getFormatSchema()` (or similar) method in a `Schema`. The same logic can be applied to `Message`.

Furthermore, I don't think I understand the difference between a `FormatMessage` and a `Schema`. If a message might either contain both keys and values, or just the values, then it seems to me that these would be two different message formats, or at least two different variations of the same message format. Since you didn't provide concrete code, I can only make assumptions, but it seems like you scatter a single responsibility over the two classes/interfaces `Schema` and `FormatMessage`, which makes everything more confusing.

Now about something in the code you provided. You cast `schemaAbstract` to `XMLSchema`. As far as I can figure out, this is unnecessary, because `Deserializer.deserializeMessage` accepts a `Schema` as an argument, and not only an `XMLSchema`. The whole point of this abstraction is that you don't need to know the concrete type of your `Schema` at compile time because the deserializer will determine at runtime what to do based on the runtime type of the passed `Schema`. So there is really no point in casting `schemaAbstract` to `XMLSchema`, you might just pass `schemaAbstract` to the deserializer directly.

And concerning the "main part" of your question: I really think it would be easier to review the class `Deserializer` if you posted its source code. However, maybe it would be better if you first responded to the points I mentioned, because, depending on how well I understood your description, redesigning the rest of your code might make everything easier to manage.

A last thing about your class/interface names. I think names like `FormatSchema` or `ParserMessage` are confusing. If I'm not mistaken, a `FormatSchema` is primarily a format, and a `ParserMessage` is primarily a parser, and "schema" and "message" only describe the format/parser further. In the English language, this would be expressed with a noun phrase where the primary noun (the "head") comes last and the modifiers precede it, like "parser factory", or "data provider". Therefore, I also think that a better name for these interfaces would be "MessageParser" or "SchemaFormat" (unless I have misunderstood the purpose of these interfaces). This can cause even more confusion when a method name contains a verb, like "setParserMessage" (at least it did for me when I read this method name).

### Update (reviewing `Deserializer` and `ParserFactory`)

OK, so about your class `Deserializer`: There is really no need to declare two `private static` variables to hold instances of `ParserMessage` and `ParserSchema`, because their sole purpose is to act as intermediate storage when invoking `deserializeSchema(Serialized, FormatSchema)` and `deserializeMessage(Serialized, Schema)`. You could instead make the methods `setParserMessage(FormatMessage)` and `setParserSchema(FormatSchema)` return a `ParserMessage` and `ParserSchema`, respectively, instead of `void` (and rename them accordingly), and just use the returned parser inside the "deserialize" methods, thereby reducing its scope to the smallest extent necessary. Otherwise, you are littering the heap with unused objects that the garbage collector can't collect because, while being assigned to a `static` field, they are still being referenced by the class `Deserializer` (and, in a way, littering the class with unused `static` fields …).

And regarding the class `ParserFactory`, I think this class can be dropped entirely by simply taking advantage of the fact that an `enum` can have fields and methods. Each `FormatSchema` could contain a field with the respective `ParserSchema`, and each `FormatMessage` could contain a field with the respective `ParserMessage` (in the following code example, I'm going to rename the interfaces by switching the order of the nouns, it's just too confusing for me otherwise):

```java
enum SchemaFormat {
    XML(new XMLSchemaParser());

    final SchemaParser schemaParser;

    SchemaFormat(SchemaParser schemaParser) {
        this.schemaParser = schemaParser;
    }
}
```

Add access modifiers if needed. Then you can just do this in `Deserializer`:

```java
public static Schema deserializeSchema(String schema, SchemaFormat schemaFormat) {
    return schemaFormat.schemaParser.parse(schema);
}
```

The same can be applied to `MessageFormat` as well. This reduces the number of methods needed in `Deserializer` to 2, namely the two "deserialize" methods. Maybe you would agree that, with such a design, the `Deserializer` class can be dropped as well, because now it is nothing more than a container for 2 `static` methods that both merely wrap another method.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63336/discussion-on-answer-by-stingy-deserializing-a-customly-formatted-string).

Comment: @Sam See above comment (my response to your last comment is there).