# Parsing various types of message strings

Tags: java, parsing, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

[Similar question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171769/deserializing-a-customly-formatted-string)

- `MessageFormat`: represents the various kinds of messages. (`XML`, `JSON`, `custom`)
- `Message`: represents an abstract Java Object for any kind of message.
- `Schema`: represents an abstract Java Object for any kind of message descriptor. (Contains `MessageFormat`.)
- `SchemaFormat`: represents all kinds of schemas. (`XSD`, `JSON Schema`, `XML` respectively for each `MessageFormat`)
- `MessageParser`: contains a method for parsing messages: `Message parse(String, Schema)`.

When I implement a `MessageParser`, I meet the following issue: I need to accept a concrete class of `Schema` in the method parameter as opposed to the `Schema` itself as it is defined in the interface. Currently, I delegate with downcasting. Should I accept `Schema` and downcast inside the method? Either way, it seems I unnecessarily cast.

```
public class FixedLengthStringMessageParser implements MessageParser {


    @Override
    public Message parse(final String msg, 
                         final Schema schemaXML
                        ) {
        return parse(msg, (XMLSchema) schemaXML);
    }

    //TODO two methods is ugly
    private FixedLengthStringMessage parse(final String msg,
                                             final XMLSchema schema
                                            ) {

        String str = msg.getData();

        HashMap<String, Long> metrics = new HashMap<>();

        int counter = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : schema.getMetrics().entrySet())
            metrics.put(entry.getKey(), Long.valueOf(str.substring(counter, counter += entry.getValue())));

        return new FixedLengthStringMessage(metrics);
    }
}
```

While I can declare the return type as `FixedLengthStringMessage` instead of the `Message`, I cannot declare the parameters in such a way, because that implementation "does not count".

Comment: I've reworded it!

Comment: `msg.getData()` seems to be a relic from when you still had the class `Serialized`, since `String` doesn't have a `getData()` method. Also, I haven't look at it in detail yet (I have to leave shortly), but I smell design flaw, and it might help if you also posted the code for `XMLSchema` to detect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation 'does not count' as it overloads the method and does not override it. You can use generics to specify the expected parameter type.

If you can change the `MessageParser` interface:

```
interface MessageParser<T extends Schema> {
    Message parse(String msg, T schema);
}
```

The implementation would be

```
public class FixedLengthStringMessageParser implements MessageParser<XMLSchema> {
    public FixedLengthStringMessage parse(String msg, XMLSchema schema) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you cannot/do not want to change the interface, you can use an intermediate abstract class to have the forwarding method only once for all implementations

```
abstract class AbstractParser<T extends Schema> implements MessageParser {
    public final Message parse(String msg, Schema schema) {
        return parse0(String msg, (T) schema);
    }
    protected abstract Message parse0(String msg, T schema);
}
```

Comment: I like the idea with generics. Thank you very much, sir :)