# A factory with static objects or an enum with instance objects?

Tags: java, memory-management, factory-method

My application accepts different messages. A `message` is described by its `schema`.

`enum` **MessageFormat**: represents `all kinds of messages`. (`XML`, `JSON`, `custom`)

`interface` **Message**: represents an abstract Java Object for `any kind of message`.

`interface` **Schema**: represents an abstract Java Object for `any kind of message` descriptor. Contains **MessageFormat**.

`enum` **SchemaFormat**: represents `all kinds of schemas`. (`XSD`, `JSON Schema`, `XML` respecively for each **MessageFormat**)

`interface` **MessageParser**: has a method `Message parse(String, Schema)`. There is one concrete for each **MessageFormat**.

`interface` **SchemaParser**: has a method `Schema parse(String)`. There is one concrete for each **SchemaFormat**.

At start-up, all of the supported schemas are loaded and parsed one time each and kept inside the memory as concrete `Schema` objects. When a message comes, we pass the message with its schema to the appropriate parser. It would be optimal to also have each appropriate parser instance inside memory (schema - parser, one-to-one). What is the best way to achieve this?

My current layout is to have a `Strategy pattern` switching the static parsers by asking a `Factory pattern` for the reference at the static parser that is inside that factory (as well as all of the parsers, for schemas and for messages, all are static).

Strategy:

```
public class Deserializer {

    private static MessageParser messageParser;
    private static SchemaParser  schemaParser;

    private Deserializer() {} // Imitating a static class

    public static Schema deserializeSchema(String schema,
                                           SchemaFormat schemaFormat
                                          ) {

        setSchemaParser(schemaFormat); // Strategy pattern
        return schemaParser.parse(schema);
    }

    public static Message deserializeMessage(String msg,
                                             Schema schema
                                            ) {

        setMessageParser(schema.getMessageFormat()); // Strategy pattern
        return messageParser.parse(msg, schema);
    }

    private static void setMessageParser(MessageFormat msgFormat) { // Strategy pattern

        messageParser = ParserFactory.getMessageParser(msgFormat); // Factory pattern
    }

    private static void setSchemaParser(SchemaFormat configFileFormat) { // Strategy pattern

        schemaParser = ParserFactory.getSchemaParser(configFileFormat); // Factory pattern
    }
}
```

Factory:

```
public class ParserFactory {

    private static final XMLSchemaParser                XML_SCHEMA_PARSER                  = new XMLSchemaParser();
    private static final FixedLengthStringMessageParser FIXED_LENGTH_STRING_MESSAGE_PARSER = new FixedLengthStringMessageParser();

    private ParserFactory() {} // imitating a static class

    public static MessageParser getMessageParser(MessageFormat msgFormat) {

        switch (msgFormat) {
            case FIXED_LENGTH_STRING:
                return getFixedLengthStringMessageParserInstance();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public static SchemaParser getSchemaParser(SchemaFormat schemaFormat) {

        switch (schemaFormat) {
            case XML:
                return getXmlSchemaParser();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    private static XMLSchemaParser getXmlSchemaParser() {
        return XML_SCHEMA_PARSER;
    }

    private static FixedLengthStringMessageParser getFixedLengthStringMessageParserInstance() {
        return FIXED_LENGTH_STRING_MESSAGE_PARSER;
    }
}
```

[I've been suggested](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/171769/deserializing-a-customly-formatted-string) to wrap all of the parsers inside the `enum`s like so:

```
enum SchemaFormat {
    XML(new XMLSchemaParser());

    final SchemaParser schemaParser;

    SchemaFormat(SchemaParser schemaParser) {
        this.schemaParser = schemaParser;
    }
}
```

And then use them like so:

```
public static Schema deserializeSchema(String schema, SchemaFormat schemaFormat) {
    return schemaFormat.schemaParser.parse(schema);
}
```

That way I can just completely delete the `Deserializer` and the `ParserFactory` classes.

If they are present, however, each Parser in lazy-initialized and as soon as it's initialized, it's kept in the memory for the rest of the time.

If I have all of the Parsers inside the enum then for each message an object gets declared and then discarded. But what happens with the performance when the application obtains 150 messages of 5 different types within a short period of time? I'm concerned that it would be really slow and the memory will bloat until the garbage collector comes and cleans it.

I also don't have the way to load the schemas at the start-up, so I may choose the option with putting the `SchemaParser`s inside the `SchemaFormat` just for the reason I will parse them once. But several data providers may choose the XML schemas, so, I that case I will instantiate the XML parser twice but that isn't a big deal, because there will not be more than 10 data providers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Multithreading

You're making multithreading really hard on yourself by using static fields in this class. Consider the following:

```
public static Schema deserializeSchema(String schema, SchemaFormat format) {
    return ParserFactory.getSchemaParser(format).parse(schema);
}

public static Message deserializeMessage(string msg, Schema schema) {
    return ParserFactory.getMessageParser(schema.getMessageFormat()).parse(msg);
}
```

This reduces all the points of failure in the Deserializer from Multithreading to naught. It's also significantly cleaner from a responsibility viewpoint. Assuming you want to get this a bit less dense, you can extract **local** variables.

#### Factory Responsibilites

It's generally more conventional to name the factory after the kind of objects it creates. Consider separating these two object types into factories of their own:

```
public final class MessageParserFactory {
    private static final MessageParser FIXED_LENGTH = new FixedLengthStringMessageParser();

    private MessageParserFactory() {}

    public static MessageParser getMessageParser(MessageFormat msgFormat) {
        switch (msgFormat) {
           case FIXED_LENGTH_STRING:
                return FIXED_LENGTH;
           default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What do you think about putting everything inside the `enum`s?

Comment: an abuse of enums ... but sure go ahead, after all java explicitly does not have actual enums ...

Comment: @Vogel612 And why, exactly, is declaring a `final` field in an enum with a (presumably) immutable type an abuse of enums?

Comment: @Stingy because enums are not supposed to be classes...

Comment: @Vogel612 Do you mean that an enum should not have fields and methods in the first place?

Comment: @Stingy from a puristic point of view, yes. I consider the way java implemented enums something between a stroke of genius and a stroke of utter madness. Lately I'm more likely to choose the latter, since Java enums are a thin wrapper of syntactic sugar over a class for almost all intents and purposes.

Comment: @Vogel612 I think I can follow your logic, but I don't see why it is a bad thing that enums behave similar to classes and are only syntactic sugar to help implement singletons. Anyway, as I understand it, your objection was not against the suggestion of making the `SchemaParser` a field of `SchemaFormat`, but rather against Java's idea of what an "enum" is and that an enum can even have a field, meaning the "abuse" you critized was actually committed by the designers of Java. This was not clear at all, because your comment was a direct response to a question about a specific enum design.

Comment: @Stingy this is why I explicitly did say "go ahead". :) Anyways, if you want to continue this discussion, feel free to ping me in [chat]. Thanks